# Protractor file upload working in Windows but script timeout in Linux

Tags: protractor

Im having a protractor test in which I upload a .csv File. It's working fine in Windows but in Linux im getting a Script Timeout.

I debugged the filepath and it looks good. I also set waitForAngular(false) before the upload and enabled it afterwards.

My Test:

```js
 describe('something', () => {
        it('somethingElse', async () => {
            await browser.get("https://somedomain.com");
            await browser.driver.sleep(2000);
            await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('mat-card-content')),5000);
            var fileToUpload = '../ressources/file.csv';
            var filepath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
            let importBtn = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));
            await importBtn.sendKeys(filepath);
            ... 
        })
 })
```

The filepath with Windows:

```
C:\Users\mat\project\ressources\file.csv
```

The filepath with Linux:

```
/home/user/project/ressources/file.csv
```

My Error Message:

```
ScriptTimeoutError: script timeout: result was not received in 100 seconds
  (Session info: headless chrome=74.0.3729.131)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-1023-aws x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/jenkins/workspace/Protractor_Stage/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/jenkins/workspace/Protractor_Stage/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/jenkins/workspace/Protractor_Stage/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

And then just giving me the describe/it lines.

Comment: Which line of code is it exactly failing?

Comment: Few assumptions - this may be because of headless chrome (for example you can't download files in headless, so maybe you can't upload either). Second, which is unlikely, your input have to be visible to sendKeys to it. So make sure it's visible, if not run `await browser.executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible'; arguments[0].style.height = '1px'; arguments[0].style.width = '1px'; arguments[0].style.opacity = 1", $input.getWebElement());`

Comment: It's due to headless chrome you used in linux box.

Comment: @NitinSahu I updated my error message. I'm not getting an error on any of my lines of code, but if I debug it stops working at ```await importBtn.sendKeys(filepath);```

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov I'm not even using headless to debug it, but it's still not working. I tried your code to make the upload button visible but it had no effect.

Comment: @yong I tried without headless mode but it's still not working. Also on windows it's working fine in headless